# How to select a range of data at index.html.erb on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am not familiar with Rails ,
I use the scaffold in ABC controller,
then it print ABC.all in the index page,
however I want to show the data which id > 100 and <500
how could I achieve this?

Because,I only knew there are first and last method.
and offset,and limit is not available method.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActiveRecord` `where` method to this. You can type a string query inside it. Here is an example:

```
ABC.where('id > 100 AND id < 500')
```

No magic, just good old `where`.
P.S.: `ActiveRecord` has tons of methods, i suggest you read this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

UPDATE:

translates_controller.rb

```
def index
  @translates = Translate.where('id > 100 AND id < 500')
  # Stuff...
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @translates.each do |t| %>
  # Stuff...
```

Comment: Not works for me (I guess I miss something?)https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23461380/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%961020725094006.png

Comment: In your case, on your controller is where you set the `@translates` variable so you can use it on your view. Lemme edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

MurifoX's answer is the best, but I wanted to point out that you can also structure this query  with order, limit and offset.

```
ABC.order(:id).offset(100).limit(399)
```

In your question, you note that limit and offset are not available methods, but they are accessible for any Rails models that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`